# Problem about the similarity between triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, geometric-transformation

Referring to the following image:

[image]

how can it be demonstrated that $AB : AC = AF : AE$ ?

The only theorem that seems to me to be useful is the *theorem of the secante and of the tangent*: $AE : DE = DE : BE $ or equally: $AF : DF = DF : CF$, but I can not conclude anything.

Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$\measuredangle ACB=\measuredangle BDA=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle BDE=\measuredangle BED,$$
which says that $\Delta ABC\sim \Delta AFE$, which gives
$$\frac{AB}{AF}=\frac{AC}{AE}$$ or
$$AB:AC=AF:AE$$ abd we are done!

Comment: It might help saying that your first $=$ comes from angles from the chord $AB$ and your third from  $\measuredangle ABD=90^{\circ}$ because $AD$ is a diameter

Comment: @Henry Yes of course. Thank you!

Comment: @TeM  You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: draw seg BD and CD and use angles in alternate segment theorem

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the inversion, then perform it at $A$ and $r=AD$. Then the circle goes to tangent at $D$ and so $D\mapsto D$, $B\mapsto E$ and $C\mapsto F$. So we have $$AB\cdot AE = AD^2 = AC\cdot AF$$